# How to collapse and expand content in flutter_markdown?

Tags: flutter, markdown, flutter-packages

These tags don't work for me on `flutter_markdown: ^0.6.14`
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown/versions/0.6.14

```markdown
<details>
<summary>Click to  show more details</summary>
More details are here!!!
</details>
```

Does `flutter_markdown` even support   tags to collapse and expand content?

Try it on Github:
https://gist.github.com/tarek360/5c699ce05fd8825040519db4651c183e